# Change imported modules imports

Tags: python, python-import, monkeypatching

How is it possible to change the imports of a imported module?

I created a package which I want to extend in a further project.
The imported package looks like this:

```
/pck_name
   /__init__.py
   /point.py
   /triangle.py
```

the point.py:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, name='test'):
        self.name = name
```

the triangle.py:

```
from pck_name.point import Point

class Triangle(object):        
    def __init__(self, points=None):    
        if points is None:
            points = list()
            for i in range(2):
                points.append(Point())         
        self.points = points
```

then I have an other project where I define a NewPoint class with a new Method:

```
class NewPoint(object):    
    def __init__(self, name='test'):
        self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)
```

what I want to achive is to import pck_name.triangle and change the imported Point with the NewPoint to get the new functionality:

```
from pck_name.triangle import Triangle

triangle = Triangle()
triangle.points[0].print_name()
```

I tried monkey-patching but if I patch the Point class it is useless as the import statement in triangle.py always imports the original Point class.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a factory (class or function) to `Triangle`'s "constructor":

```
class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, points=None, factory=None):
        if points is None:
            if factory is None:  
                # instead of raising an error, you can use Point class by default
                raise ValueError("Both points and factory not provided")
            points = [factory() for _ in range(3)]
        self.points = points
```

Now you can use it in the following way:

```
triangle = Triangle()  # raises error
triangle = Triangle(points=...)  # uses provided points
triangle = Triangle(factory=NewPoint)  # creates a triangle with NewPoints
```

**Edit:** additionally, if you want to make some kind of aliases, you can use `functools.partial`:

```
NewPointTriangle = functools.partial(Triangle, factory=NewPoint)
DefaultPointTriangle = functools.partial(Triangle, factory=Point)
```

and now:

```
triangle = NewPointTriangle()  # creates NewPoints
triangle = DefaultPointTriangle()  # creates Points

triangle = NewPointTriangle(points=...)  # uses provided points
triangle = DefaultPointTriangle(points=...)  # uses provided points
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This could be a solution, but is this also possible without changes in the imported package? One reason for this would be the usage of a package I did not create on my own, so I can not change the package code. Another reason would be that this solution makes the code unnecessary complicated for other users who use the package iteself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to modify the behavior of Triangle class without actually "touching" the code. This is not the best or elegant approach, but maybe it will be somehow useful:

- Modify Triangle.points list when NewPoint is imported:

```
import sys

if sys.modules.get('NewPoint'):

  # clear and update the Triangle.points list
  triangle.__dict__['points'].clear()

  for i in range(2):
    triangle.__dict__['points'].append(NewPoint())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For now I have solved the problem by overwriting the imported modules. The disadvantage is that I have to import and overwrite the modules in the correct order. This means I have to import and overwrite the class or function which I want to overwrite before it is imported anywhere else. This is not a perfect solution as it is very difficult to figure out when something is imported.
A friend told me he solved a related problem with helper functions. Do you have any experience with that?